# My Macro is runnig but skipping rows

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code to move anything thats ordered to another sheet and it works besides for the fact that it skips rows and i have to run a few times to get everything moved, any help would greatly appreciated
thanks

```
Sub MoveLS()
    Dim h As Variant
    Dim endrow As Integer
    Dim SB As Worksheet, ORDERED As Worksheet

    Set SB = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("SB")
    Set ORDERED = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("ORDERED")


    endrow = SB.Range("A" & SB.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row


    For h = 2 To endrow

        If SB.Cells(h, "H").Value = "Ordered" Then
           SB.Cells(h, "H").EntireRow.Cut Destination:=ORDERED.Range("A" & ORDERED.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
           SB.Cells(h, "H").EntireRow.Delete


        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

As you iterate over the rows you're skipping some.

Instead delete from the bottom up like so:

```
For h = endrow to 2 Step -1
    If SB.Cells(h, "H").Value = "Ordered" Then
       SB.Cells(h, "H").EntireRow.Cut Destination:=ORDERED.Range("A" & ORDERED.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
       SB.Cells(h, "H").EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that every time you cut a row, you are also skipping the next row.

E.g.

- Your index is 5.
- row 5 match your condition
- you cut row 5 and you paste it into another sheet

  - row 6 becames the new row 5
  - the index moves to 6
  - row 6 (previously row 7) is evaluated and the prior row 6 is skipped.

Try to copy the row instead of cut it!

Comment: i needed to cut as i dont want them on the page anymore but thanks for the explanation as to why its happening